# What is the best way to draw a tree diagram in manim?

Tags: python, manim

I'm very new to learning manim and well python. However, I'm trying to learn it to make nice videos for my students. I'm attempting to create some tree diagrams in manim, but I can't seem to find much help. I tried getting manim to use tikz, but I'm having trouble with that as well. Is there a nice way to make tree diagrams straight in manim?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Well, I've made a lot of attempts. Can't find much. I've seen lots of people ask questions like this on here.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is that you create a class yourself to generate the trees, it is not complicated if you know how to order elements with VGroup and program the unions between each Node, since it is a personal project you will have to develop it on your own, you can also check Manim's Discord to request help from the community, the link is in the official Manim repository.